# foreach bootstrap Accordion

Tags: jquery, laravel, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make this thing same as [this one](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=accordion). I already printed. But collapse expend is not working.

```
<div class="bs-example">
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
@foreach($faqs as $faq)
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">{{ $faq->title }}</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>{{ $faq->description }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: Your `collapseOne` id is not unique since it's in a loop.

Comment: Sir i tried like `href="{{ $i++ }}"` `div id="{{ $i++ }}"` it was same .

Comment: This will increase the `$i` 2 times every iteration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you correctly imported the dependencies, this should work (making the ids unique):

```
<div class="bs-example">
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
@foreach($faqs as $index => $faq)
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-{{ $index }}">{{ $faq->title }}</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse-{{ $index }}" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>{{ $faq->description }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: almost working i guess. but expend , collapse is not working . i just don't get it why.

Comment: What do you mean by almost working? Any difference from your attempt? Also are there maybe any errors printed in the console?

Comment: It printed every single panel. But ` href="#collapse-{{ $index }}">` and div id="collapse-{{ $index }}" are not working .

Comment: Can you check the HTML source (Ctrl + U) that the `href="#collapse.."` and `id="collapse.."` actually have correct incrementing indexes?